# How to convert a nested hash map key (string) into a double

Tags: java, hashmap, nested

I have a nested hash map and I don't know how to convert the keys into a double. I have to convert them because later on I have to do some calculations. Is there anyway to convert them. The reason why I am doing this is because I want to map three elements together: the radius, theta, and the amplitude. As I read them in from an image which come in a specific format I would like to save that in hash map (I found the most convenient since it maps out elements). So I tried lists and array lists but I couldn't get it to save three elements so I used a nested hash map.

Here is my code:

```
    // create a Map()
    original = new LinkedHashMap<List<RadTheta>,String>();
    List<RadTheta> list = new ArrayList<RadTheta>();
    // create a Map()

    for(int i =0; i< 256;i++){
         for(int y=0; y< 256; y++){

            //reading in the values.
            String x = image.getLocationAsString(i, y);
            String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);

            //Parsing them into "key" and "value".
            String delim = ", value=";
            String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
            double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
            String stringNum = String.valueOf(num);
            //System.out.println(num);

            String [] t = x.split("r=");
            String[] b = t[1].split(" mm/c");
            //System.out.print("Meet b:    "+b[0]);
            double radius = Double.parseDouble(b[0]);
            String stringRad = String.valueOf(radius);
            //System.out.print("The radius:   "+radius);

            String [] split = x.split("theta= ");
            String [] split2 = split[1].split(Character.toString(IJ.degreeSymbol));
            double theta = Double.parseDouble(split2[0]);
            //System.out.println("  theta: "+theta);
            String stringTheta = String.valueOf(theta);

            RadTheta rad = new RadTheta(radius, theta);
            list.add(rad);
            original.put(list, stringNum);

            //System.out.println(stringRad+"  theta= "+stringTheta+"  value= "+stringNum);



         }
    }
```

Here I am iteration through the hash map and I want to convert the key (radius, theta) value to a double because then I have do some calculation on them. Is there any way to convert this?

```
  public void outputData(PrintWriter write){
    write.println("Radius" +"  Theta  "+"  Amplitude");
    saveData();
    Iterator iter = original.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iter.next();

            //This is the problem-------------------------------
        double currKey = Double.parseDouble(pairs.getKey());
        double currValue = Double.parseDouble((String) pairs.getValue());
        write.println(currKey +"    "+currValue);

        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = "+ pairs.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing, using a `Map<String,String>` as a ***key*** in another map, violates the basic requirements for a map key.  Keys must be _immutable_ and a Map is not... its hashCode will change every time you add or remove an element.  Maybe if you explain what you're trying to accomplish we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure you want a map whose key is another map?  `rTheta` is a map that keeps growing, so that by the time you've reached the end of the two `for` loops, it has 65536 elements in it.  Why do you want to use this as a `Map` key?  Do you know what a `Map` is for?  Perhaps you really want a `List` of some kind?

Comment: This is clearly an XY problem.  The OP's original, real issue is being masked by the incorrect approach in the given code.  I would strongly suggest the OP rewrite the question explaining the actual objectives, with sample input and desired output.

Comment: @ajb I wanted to map there elements together: radius, theta and amplitude. The only way I could think of is a nested hash map. I couldn't put three elements with lists or array lists.

Comment: Could you create a class that contains three members: radius, theta, and amplitude and then create new instances of this class as needed and add them to a collection?

Comment: What do you mean by "I wanted to _map_ three elements together"?  I have a feeling you're using the verb _map_ in a way that's different from how Java uses the term.  And the right way to create a list with three elements in each list element is to define a `class` with three members or properties, then create a `List` of that class.

Comment: @ajb the reason why I have to use a map is before this code I have written code where I do the summation of values that correspond to the radius. The image contains many radius that are repeated over and over because the amplitude and thetas are different. So when I do the summations I first check the radius and if the hash map is empty then I add the radius with its corresponding value. Then next time I come across the same radius number, instead of adding it to the hash map I just add the value.

Comment: @ErikGillespie So because I have to do the summation of amplitude I think I need to use a hash map. Also cause it needs to pair the values with the radius it is associated with.

Comment: But then the `Map` key should be the radius, since that's what your searching for, right?  It shouldn't be another map.

Comment: If you need to sum up the amplitudes for a given pair of (radius, theta) then you could create a class (RadTheta) to capture the radius/theta tuple and then create a Map&lt;RadTheta,Double> to easily lookup an amplitude by radius and theta and add to the amplitude.

Comment: @ErikGillespie okay I changed the hash map which know carrys a list and that list of type RadTheta class which I created that contains getters and setters. But I still can't access my keys and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just converting keys and value from a Map looks right by what you are doing.  Here is a really simply code snippet that work like what you are trying to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        myMap.put("1.123456", "-1.123456");
        myMap.put("2.123456", "-2.123456");

        for(String keys : myMap.keySet()){

            double keyDouble = Double.parseDouble(keys);
            double valueDouble = Double.parseDouble(myMap.get(keys));

            System.out.println(String.format("Key: %f Value: %f", keyDouble, valueDouble));
        }
    }
```

If yours is not working, can you post your error?  Also follow the comment's suggestion on not using a Map as a key.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a class with 3 doubles and use a list of that class:

```
class Value {
  double theta;
  double radius;
  double amp;
}

List<Value> values = new ArrayList();

// fill list with values
for (Value val: values) {
  System.out.println("Theta="+val.theta+", Radius="+val.radius+", Amp="+val.amp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it now. Yeah I think a list is a much better idea then the hash maps. And its good that they are paired together. Is there a difference between doing this List<RadTheta> list = new ArrayList<RadTheta>(); and what you did?

Comment: If you're using java 6 or below then you must use `new ArrayList<RadTheta>()`. If you're using java 7 then the compiler is smart enough to infer the generic type so it's ok to use `new ArrayList()`